# How to make Ping() give fast respond

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, ping, indy

Before TADOConnection connect to a database (it makes long trial connect if ip addres not valid or not exitst), I'm using a Ping method from TIdIcmpClient component to check valid ip address, but I don't know why sometime very fast respond and sometime very slow respond. How to makes Ping fast (just a few second, under 5 secs is better)?

Thank you !

```
IdIcmpClient1.ReceiveTimeout:=200;
IdIcmpClient1.Host:='202.345.7.456'; // for example
IdIcmpClient1.Protocol:=1;
IdIcmpClient1.Ping();
if IdIcmpClient1.ReplyStatus.ReplyStatusType=rsEcho then
begin
  ADOConnection1.Connected:=True; // try to connect to database
end else
begin
  Exit; // cancel connection
end;
```

Comment: Surely it's just easier to try to connect to the database and deal with errors if they arise? I can't fathom your use of ping here at all.

Comment: Because if the host not connected or wrong host ip address (ip address can edit by user manually), direct connecting to host database takes times, a minute minimal, can be a few minutes

Comment: If I were you I'd ask about that. I doubt that ping is really the answer.

Comment: I just try to make the application not looks freeze while TADOConnection try to connect to invalid address. Do you have another idea without ping? Using thread is not my choice.

Comment: That's now a different question. This question asks about ping. Indeed the code in the question which refers to database seems to be a distraction if you want to ask about ping. Now, if you want to ask about your program freezing when connecting to the database that would require a question edit. If you rule out threads then there might not be a solution. This is the nature of TCP/IP. You simply can't predict how long a response will take to arrive.

Comment: So the answer is we can't predict how long a response will take to arrive?

Comment: You realise that `TAdoConnection` has a `ConnectionTimeout` property?  Try setting it to 1.  The actual timeout seems to take a bit longer than that (maybe x2) but it's simpler than messing about with Ping.

Comment: @MartynA You said :  
Well, I've tried my code in D7 .. Seattle and what the results tell me is that the AdoConnection will not time out in under about 9.2 seconds, regardless of what you set the value to be. The AdoConnection1.ConnectionTimeout is simply passed on to the Ado ConnectionObject attached to it, and that's on the "other side" of the COM interface, so if it doesn't respond how you want, there is, afaik, nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @FZS: I'd forgotten that answer.  I haven't consciously changed anything  on my LAN has changed since then, but the minimum AdoConnection Timeout has gone down to 2.8 seconds.  I wonder if a Win10 update is responsible?  Anyway, I'll update that answer, thanks for pointing it out.  Not my -1, btw.

Comment: It's not guaranteed that a server will respond to a ping, so you may get the false impression that the database is down, while it would respond to an actual connection attempt.

Comment: What database are you connecting to? If it is SQL server you can try to open socket on port 1433 it works faster for me then pinging and also shows if server is down when machine is up

Comment: @MartynA ConnectionTimeout only regulates timeout of connection to server if server is up, there is also TCP connection timeout that is impossible to change.

Comment: @EugeneK Yes, I'm using MS SQL Server